# Can't get the values of input texts which are dynamically created by ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I'm trying to post the values that I get from a form with an Ajax function. First of all, I use another Ajax function to list the datas as a table from a database. After that to edit selected data, I am trying to use an Ajax function which does not work. Here are my functions; the last one does not post any data. I can add any necessary information if you need.

AJAX:

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var clickCheck = 1;
            $('select').change(function(){
                clickCheck = 1;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ajaxTest4.php',
                    data: $('#classForm').serialize(),
                    dataType: "html",
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $('#result').html('<img src="loading.gif"/>');
                    },
                    success:function(answer){
                        $('#result').html(answer);// birden fazla data nasıl çekilecek
                        console.log("Sended1");
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert("An error has occured !");
                    }         
                });
            });
            $('#result').on("click", "a", function(){
                var order = this.id;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ajaxTest4.php',
                    data:{id:order},
                    dataType: "html",
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $('#result').html('<img src="loading.gif"/>');
                    },
                    success:function(answer){
                        $('#result').html(answer);// birden fazla data nasıl çekilecek
                        console.log("Sended2");
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert("An error has occured !");
                    }         
                });
            });
            $('#result').on("click", ".delete", function(){
                var order = this.id;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'delete.php',
                    data:{id:order},
                    dataType: "html",
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $('#result').html('<img src="loading.gif"/>');
                    },
                    success:function(answer){
                        $('#result').html(answer);// birden fazla data nasıl çekilecek
                        console.log("Sended3");
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert("An error has occured !");
                    }         
                });
            });
            $('#result').on("dblclick", ".doubleClick", function(){
                $('.hiddenInput').fadeIn();
            });
            //var grade1 = $('#grade11').val();
            //var grade2 = $('#grade22').val();
            $('#result').on("click", ".edit", function(){
                //var order = this.id;
                //alert(grade1+" "+grade2);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'edit.php',
                    data:$('#tableForm').serialize(),
                    dataType: "html",
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $('#result').html('<img src="loading.gif"/>');
                    },
                    success:function(answer){
                        $('#result').html(answer);// birden fazla data nasıl çekilecek
                        console.log("Sended4");
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert("An error has occured !");
                        console.log("errorEdit.php");
                    }         
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <h3>Get Student</h3>
    <form id="classForm">
        <div id="classSelectionLabelDiv">
            <label for="classSelection">Select Class</label>
        </div>
        <div id="classSelectionDiv">
            <select id="classSelection" name="class">
                <option value="" selected="selected">--Select--</option>
                <option value="1A">1A</option>
                <option value="1B">1B</option>
                <option value="1C">1C</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
    </br>
    <div id="result">

    </div>
</body>
```

ajaxTest4.php:

```
include './config.php';

if(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest'){
    die('Wrong request !');
}
$sql='';
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $sql = "WHERE ID = '".$db -> real_escape_string($_POST['id'])."'";
}else{
    $sql = "WHERE Class = ?";
}
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM test1 $sql");
if($stmt == "false"){
    die('Query error !'.$db->error);  
}
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $stmt -> execute();
    $result = $stmt -> get_result();
    $student = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    echo "<form id='tableForm' method='POST'>";
    echo "<table>";
    echo"<tr><td align='center'>".$student['StudentID']."</td>";
    echo"<td align='center'>".$student['FirstName']."</td>";
    echo"<td align='center'>".$student['LastName']."</td>";
    echo"<td align='center'>".$student['Class']."</td>";
    echo"<td align='center' class='doubleClick' id='grade1'>".$student['Grade1'].'<input type="text" class="hiddenInput" id="grade11" name="grade11" size="2" hidden/>'."</td>";
    echo"<td align='center' class='doubleClick' id='grade2'>".$student['Grade2'].'<input type="text" class="hiddenInput" id="grade22" name="grade22" size="2" hidden/>'."</td>";
    echo"<td align='center'><a class='edit' id='".$student['ID']."'>Edit</a></td>";
    echo"<td align='center'><a class='delete' id='".$student['ID']."'>Delete</a></td>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</form>";
}
else{
    $stmt -> bind_param("s",$_POST['class']);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $result = $stmt -> get_result();
    echo 'There is/are '.$result->num_rows." ".'record(s)';
    echo '
    <table> 
    <tr >
        <td align="center">Student ID</td>
        <td align="center">First Name</td>
        <td align="center">Last Name</td>
        <td align="center">Class</td>
        <td align="center">Grade 1</td>
        <td align="center">Grade 2</td>
        <td align="center">Details</td>
    </tr>';
    while($student = $result ->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
        echo"<tr><td align='center'>".$student['StudentID']."</td>";
        echo"<td align='center'>".$student['FirstName']."</td>";
        echo"<td align='center'>".$student['LastName']."</td>";
        echo"<td align='center'>".$student['Class']."</td>";
        echo"<td align='center'>".$student['Grade1']."</td>";
        echo"<td align='center'>".$student['Grade2']."</td>";
        echo"<td align='center'><a id='".$student['ID']."'>Click</a></td>";
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
$db->close();?>
```

edit.php:

```
if(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest'){
    die('Wrong request !');
}
$updatedGrade1 = $_POST['grade11'];
$updatedGrade2 = $_POST['grade22'];

echo 'Grade1:'.$updatedGrade1.'</br>';
echo 'Grade2:'.$updatedGrade2.'</br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the last Ajax tries to serialize the `#tableForm` Form.
Within that, there are two input fields, provided by your php:

```
    echo"<td align='center' class='doubleClick' id='grade1'>".$student['Grade1'].'<input type="text" class="hiddenInput" id="grade11" name="grade11" size="2" hidden/>'."</td>";
    echo"<td align='center' class='doubleClick' id='grade2'>".$student['Grade2'].'<input type="text" class="hiddenInput" id="grade22" name="grade22" size="2" hidden/>'."</td>";
```

There is no such parameter "hidden", btw. It should be `<input type="hidden" ...` but that's only aside.

These two fields do not have any value. Thus: what do you expect to get serialized?
The Form and it's fields do not have any valid data, so at least this results in an empty object string: `"{}"`

Comment: I am trying to get the values of input boxes which will be type by an user.

Comment: You have already seen them. The input boxes that you used in your answer.